# How to solve HTTPS issue in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <script>

 $.getJSON('https://test.engageport.com/rest/mobile/1', function (data) {
            var ordercodes = $.map(data.data, function(entry){

            Result= entry.ordercode; }
   }
</script>
```

I am using json url as https://test.engageport.com/rest/mobile/1. In phone-gap i cant get the response. I am getting error like data['null'] is not an object. How to solve this issue. http url is working fine. HTTPS is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTTPS url does not provide a valid SSL Certificate, so your application can't reach it.
You can use a valid certificate or install your untrusted certificate on your phone.